# How to build a package from source?

Tags: ros3djs, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi, source, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I've recently installed the ROS indigo desktop version in my raspberry PI 2, running the last version of Raspbian (following the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi). I've installed all properly. Now I'm trying to install new packages from source in the ROS file system, but I don't understand exactly what I have to do to get it. The package I'm trying to install is ros3djs (http://wiki.ros.org/ros3djs).
The steps I've followed are the next:

1-
`$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/src`

2-
`$ git clone https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs.git`

Once I have the package downloaded in the src folder, I don't know exactly what I  should do. In the installation of ROS tutorial comes the next command to invoke catkin_make_isolated:

`$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo`

but it makes all the workspace to be compiled again and it takes a lot of time, so what I should do? I want to  compile only the new packages I add.
Being on the ros_catkin_ws folder, I've tried the next:

3-  `$ catkin_make --pkg ros3djs`

But I get the next message:

> Packages "ros3djs" not found in the workspace

I've also tried the catkin_make_isolated:

3- `$ catkin_make_isolated --pkg ros3djs`

> Packages not found in the workspace:
> ros3djs

I don't understand very well the structure ROS have to add new packages.
Could someone give me any suggestion?
Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210842/how-to-build-a-package-from-source?/) by [rubenvm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22020/rubenvm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs.git
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
$ catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$ source ~/ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Note that I don't know anything about the package in question, but that should work.

EDIT: Just looked at the GitHub repo. The package you are trying to use is **not** a catkin package. See this page:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/catkin/CreatingPackage

Every catkin package needs, at minimum, a CMakeLists.txt file and a package.xml file. This repo appears to have neither.

For build instructions, see the repo's [README.md](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs/blob/develop/utils/README.md) file.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubenvm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22020/rubenvm/) on 2015-06-09**:
Yes, you are right, I have installed that following the instructions given. But the main problem is that I have 188 packages aproximately within the src folder, so when I want to add a single package the catkin_make command make it to compile everything, which takes a lot of time in raspberry.Thanks

**Comment by [Progtologist](https://answers.ros.org/users/11081/progtologist/) on 2015-06-09**:
You should create different workspaces depending on what you need or install the files you use (in opt for example) and overlay workspaces with your projects.
[Workspace Overlaying](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying)

**Comment by [rubenvm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22020/rubenvm/) on 2015-06-10**:
Thank you very much! It is just what I was looking for!
Thank you all for your help